# JSON.net: converting 1 object into 2 separate arrays without a parent – with JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

**JSON.net**: How to convert/split *1 object* into *2 separate arrays* without a parent node with *JsonConverter*?

**JSON – actual**:

```
{"Name":"Bus",
 "Type":"Vehicle",
 "SymCollection":[
    {"ids":[0,1]},
    {"weights":[100,50]}
]}
```

**JSON – expected**:

```
{"Name":"Bus",
 "Type":"Vehicle",
 "ids":[0,1],
 "weights":[100,50]
}
```

**C# – source object (cannot be changed)**:

```
class TestClass
{
    public string Name;
    public string Type;
    public SymCollection SymCollection;
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(SymCollectionConverter))]
class SymCollection
{
    public int[] Ids;
    public int[] Weights;
}
```

---

**C# – *JsonConverter*.** How do I change it?

```
class SymCollectionConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            SymCollection inputContainer = (SymCollection)value;

            // Need to delete next line – do not need any parent node.
            writer.WriteStartArray();


            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("ids");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var id in inputContainer.Ids)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(id);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.WriteEndObject();


            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName("weights");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var weight in inputContainer.Weights)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(weight);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.WriteEndObject();


            // So, and delete next line too.
            writer.WriteEndArray();

        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return typeof(SymCollection) == objectType;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, the structure of the *TestClass* and *SymCollection* cannot be changed.

---

**UPDATE 1**: one of the possible solutions, as proposed by [Pavel Anikhouski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509533/json-net-converting-1-object-into-2-separate-arrays-without-a-parent-with-jso/60510738#60510738), partially handmade without *JsonConverter*:

```
class TestClass
{
    public string Name;
    public string Type;

    [JsonIgnore]// Ignore and process it manually.
    public SymCollection SymCollection;

    public string ToJson()
    {
        // --> MAIN ATTENTION HERE <

        // Create JSON without SymCollection.
        var resultJObject = JObject.FromObject(this);

        // Add missing IDs and weights.
        var symbolIdsAndWeights = SymCollection.GetIdsAndWeightsJTokens();
        resultJObject.Add(symbolIdsAndWeights.ids);
        resultJObject.Add(symbolIdsAndWeights.weights);

        // Convert to string.
        string resultJson = resultJObject.ToString(Formatting.None);
        return resultJson;
    }


}

[JsonConverter(typeof(SymCollectionConverter))]
class SymCollection
{
    public int[] Ids;
    public int[] Weights;

    public (JToken ids, JToken weights) GetIdsAndWeightsJTokens()
    {
        JTokenWriter idsWriter = new JTokenWriter();
        idsWriter.WriteStartObject();
        idsWriter.WritePropertyName("ids");
        idsWriter.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var id in Ids)
        {
            idsWriter.WriteValue(id);
        }
        idsWriter.WriteEndArray();
        idsWriter.WriteEndObject();

        JTokenWriter weightsWriter = new JTokenWriter();
        weightsWriter.WriteStartObject();
        weightsWriter.WritePropertyName("weights");
        weightsWriter.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var weight in Weights)
        {
            weightsWriter.WriteValue(weight);
        }
        weightsWriter.WriteEndArray();
        weightsWriter.WriteEndObject();


        return (idsWriter.Token.First, weightsWriter.Token.First);

    }
}
```

And usage as:

```
TestClass testObject = new TestClass();
string resultJsonStr = testObject.ToJson();
Console.WriteLine(resultJsonStr);
```

Comment: Have you considered `JsonConverter` as only an option here? Does `Json.Linq` make sense for you?

Comment: delete ``]`` in the last line from your expected ``json``

Comment: @Sajid thanks, fixed!

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski May you, please, post a simple example of how to fix it with LINQ? The real class behind TestClass is huge, so it would be really nice to fix the SymCollection only.

Comment: @OlegZarevennyi I've added an answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to rewrite your json using `Json.Linq`. Parse value to [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), then enumerate `SymCollection` items (since it's an array), then go through every item properties and add each property to the parent, using `Name` and `Value` of [`JProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm). Finally remove `SymCollection` token

```cs
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach (JObject item in jObject["SymCollection"])
{
    foreach (var property in item.Properties())
    {
        jObject.Add(property.Name, property.Value);
    }
}

jObject.Remove("SymCollection");
var result = jObject.ToString();
```

Maybe, the inner `for` loop is redundant, you can get only a first property of every `SymCollection` item without using a loop (if you sure of that).

The code above produces the following output

```
{
  "Name": "Bus",
  "Type": "Vehicle",
  "ids": [
    0,
    1
  ],
  "weights": [
    100,
    50
  ]
}
```

Comment: Honestly, I hope that there is a better and easier way, but it helped to solve this problem. In some sense, it is half handmade. I have added the solution based on your answer to my question (see: UPDATE 1).

Comment: @OlegZarevennyi Good solution! But personally I'd like to avoid mixing `JsonConverter` and `Json.Linq`. You can easily convert `JToken`/`JObject` to the instance of specific type and back. Anyway, everything depends on your requirements and existing code base